# Threaded ldap modify on a web application

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, ldap, spring-batch

I have a web application which does a daily search on an ldap database. This is done through spring ldap library on a sheduled task. This search will return about 20000 results. Then I wish to modify an attribute on all of these users which is where the problems start. I really wish there was a group modify function like in a relational database you would do something like (set a=x where b

So I have tried two approaches:

loop over each user, and do something that looks like this:

```
DistinguishedName userDn = buildDn(user);
  DirContextOperations dtCtx = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(userDn);

  for(int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++){
      dtCtx.setAttributeValue(attributes[i], values[i]);
  }
  ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dtCtx);
```

Which works, but is very time consuming.

The second approach is the same as the first, but chop the list of users and multi thread the modify. Which works much faster, but still does not scale well. The ldap is an opends datastore.

Is there a better way to do a batch modify on ldap from a web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could look at a `Spring Batch` pattern where a single list of all users is built up, then, using a thread pool, each user is passed, modified and committed to the ldap server.

a configuration might look like this;

```
<batch:job id="ldapJob">
    <batch:step id="ldapJob.step1">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor">
            <batch:chunk reader="ldapReader" processor="ldapModifier" writer="ldapWriter" commit-interval="1"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor"/>
```

with the reader like this

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.batch.item.reader;

import java.util.Queue;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;

public class LdapItemReader implements ItemReader<DirContextOperations> {

    private Queue<DirContextOperations> dirContextOperations;

    public DirContextOperations read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        if (dirContextOperations == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                //load up the dirContextOperations into the queue
            }//end synch
        }//end if
        //retrieve
        return dirContextOperations.poll();
    }

}
```

a processor;

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.batch.item.processor;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;

public class LdapItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<DirContextOperations, DirContextOperations> {

    public DirContextOperations process(DirContextOperations item) throws Exception {
        //do some update
        item.setAttributeValue(null, null);
        //return
        return item;
    }

}
```

and finally the writer to the ldap server

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.batch.item.writer;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;

public class LdapItemWriter implements ItemWriter<DirContextOperations> {

    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    public void write(List<? extends DirContextOperations> items) throws Exception {
        for (DirContextOperations operation : items) {
            ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(operation);
        }
    }

    public void setLdapTemplate(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
        this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
    }

}
```

the key thing in this pattern is the use of a taskexecutor to allow you to multi-thread the process, with the reader being responsible for first building the Queue/List (of 20k records) then each thread would poll for a user, make the changes, the put it back.

this pattern doesn't allow for retries so you may want to look at the loading strategy, but it will give you a decent thread pool scalable update solution that can run in an WAR.

have a look at [spring-batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html) for more information

Comment: Thank you so much! Im going to try this. I did not know about the spring batch libraries.. at the moment I am managing this with java executor. This looks much better thank you.